# Cannot get text in Edittext in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I write a method that show a dialog with a `EditText` and button and when button pressed My app should be get the value of `EditText` but for ever `EditText` is empty, Why?

```
private void lookupNumber(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialognumber);
    final EditText eNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getNumber);
    Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String number=eNumber.getText().toString();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change

```
 final EditText eNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getNumber);
```

to

```
 final EditText eNumber=(EditText)dailog.findViewById(R.id.getNumber);
```

Comment: Yes this is my Answer Thank u